# Why object in vector of vectors doesn't get created

Tags: c++, vector

In this code:

```
vector<vector<int> > outer_vec;
outer_vec.push_back(vector<int> inner_vec);  //THIS FAILS
```

but this one:

```
vector<vector<int> > outer_vec;
vector<int> inner_vec;
outer_vec.push_back(inner_vec);  //THIS WORKS FINE
```

All in all why in first case the object `inner_vec` is not getting created.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your syntax is incorrect. If you just want to push back a new `vector` it should be:

```
std::vector<std::vector<int>> outer_vec;
outer_vec.push_back(std::vector<int>());
```

Where you just create a new `vector` with `std::vector<int>()`

Comment: Can you provide me a link for this constructor

Comment: @AgrudgeAmicus The first constructor [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/vector/)